# mysql ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY not keeping disabled

Tags: mysql

I have disabled the sql mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from phpmyadmin but after several days it come back and make explode the query below. There is a way to make disabled permanently the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY or how to make it work the query with this option enabled?
Thanks

```
select a.id as assegnazione_id, d.colore as stato_colore, d.nome as stato_label, 
  a.commessa_id as id, c.titolo as macro, b.titolo as titolo, a.scadenza, 
  a.ore as tempo_stimato, a.voce_id, c.colore, a.titolo as titolo_user, 
  a.user_id, a.stato 
from commesse_assegnazioni a 
left join commesse_voci b on a.voce_id=b.id 
left join commesse_voci c on b.macro_id=c.id 
left join sys_stati d on a.stato=d.id 
where a.commessa_id=99 and a.user_id = 1 
  and b.parent_id!=0 and a.stato != 20 
  and a.scadenza is not null 
group by a.voce_id,a.user_id,a.titolo 
order by a.scadenza asc
```

Comment: Yes, change the parameter in `my.ini`/`my.cnf` then it will carry over even if mysql is restarted

Comment: Or use set persist

Comment: Why are you using GROUP BY at all? Your has no aggregate functions in the select-list. If you remove the GROUP BY clause, then the query will work. If you keep the GROUP BY clause, then all the columns besides the three named in your GROUP BY clause need to be in aggregate expressions.